# Response curve of an LDR?

Tags: ldr

Can someone tell me (or link me) the response curve of an LDR. I don't mean the frequency response, just the intensity response; is it linear, or logarithmic?

Comment: LDR == Light dependent resistor?

Comment: It's what I would expect to find on the LDR's data sheet ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [the Advanced Photonix PDV-P9004](http://www.advancedphotonix.com/ap_products/pdfs/PDV-P9004.pdf), it seems like the illuminance is proportional to the conductance (1/resistance) of the photoresistor.  At some point it probably saturates.

This makes sense as the photons it receives and the applied electric field should be proportional to the electrons that flow.  It might not be purely linear between the field (voltage) and resistance though.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nick. In response to the comments on my OP, yeah, I should have thought of that. :-(

Comment: That does not look proportional to me... The slope is closer to a conductance that is proportional to the square root of the illuminance.